# Python 3.3, Issues with PATH

Tags: python

All, 
I am just beginning with learning Python 3.3. 
After installing Python 3.3 and having the installer update my `PATH` (on Windows Vista) automatically, I am trying just typing `python` from any directory on my `C:\` drive and am receiving an error:

> python is not recognized as an internal or external command.

ONLY when I navigate to `c:\Python33` and run `python` does it recognize the program and show the version number.

I manually went to my Environment variables in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced settings -> Environment Variables -> PATH, to make sure c:\Python33 is listed in the PATH.

Am I missing something else?

Comment: Try starting a new command prompt, **after** you changed the PATH variable.

Comment: Basic questions about using the command line are not programming questions and do not really belong on Stack Overflow. Maybe try Super User.

Comment: Try `echo %PATH%` to make sure it's really there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, everyone! 
I tried a new command prompt window, restarting machine, uninstall/re-install and none worked. Thought it was too much to take at the start of my practice and settled with version 2.7.3 instead :)

Comment: What happens when you `echo %PATH%`?